# Как производители определяют что видеокарта использовалась для майнинга?

Tags: железо, видеокарта, майнинг

Когда просматривал характеристики видеокарты, увидел такую фразу:

> при использовании для майнинга гарантия 6 месяцев

Как производители определяют что видеокарта использовалась для майнинга? Гугл дал только косвенные ответы: перепрошитый Биос, задратые до предела частоты и т.п., хотя фанаты (игроки) делают точно тоже самое.

Comment: Может там часы наработки куда-то пишутся, как в жёстких дисках? )  Или тупо какие-нибудь вздувшиеся конденсаторы смотрят ))

Answer (score 1):

Майнинг обычно проводится в довольно жестких условиях, то есть оборудование буквально заставляют работать в условиях повышенной температуры и на максимальных возможностях – высоких частотах и при полном тайминге памяти, все это через какое-то время приводит к тому, что карта "не вывозит". Проверить это можно с помощью игр и спец. утилит.

Если у тебя хорошая карта не позволяет нормально играть в среднеграфонистую игру, все фризерит и лагает, то стоит задуматься. Конечно, это очень примитвный способ и проблемы в игре будут зависить от износа.

Другой способ - утилиты. Например, Nvidia позволяет проверить свою карту прямо через [сайт](https://www.nvidia.com/ru-ru/). Три самый распространенные программы для проверки: FurMark, Msi Afterburner, EVGA OC Scanner X. [Тут](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/mizhgunit/kak-proverit-videokartu-posle-maininga-pri-pokupke-spisok-programm-i-deistvii-600a91a046ad05621802d091) можно почитать подробнее. Проверяют перегрев, битую память, возможность выдавать заявленные параметры при нагрузке. Если все параметры просели, значит можно предположить майнинг.

Конечно, некоторые геймеры тоже "урабатывают" свои карты и универсальной проверки пока нет, об этом кстати недавно говорили как о проблеме. По-моему AMD [хотели как-то ограничивать мощность карты](https://habr.com/ru/news/t/547678/) при подозрении на майнинг, но отказались от этой идеи, т.к. нет однозначенного маркера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть однозначного способа нет, и все они являются косвенными? Получается, если не вносить никаких изменений в биос, и сильно не разгонять можно юзать. Причина вопроса: цена них очень высокая, а моя вот как бы на днях не умерла. Ждать конца года что они выйдут на свои цены (в чём я сильно сомневаюсь), нет возможности, вот и возник вопрос, отбить хоть какую-то часть, без особых нагрузок на неё.

Comment: Отдельно можно посмотреть видео здесь https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZIXWNZ1SY0&ab_channel=The4atlanin Но еще наткнулась на инфу про логи https://support.nvidia.eu/hc/ru/articles/212564065-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8-GeForce-Experience-NVIDIA- Однако подробнее узнать пока не смогла